# I'm new to Golang and would like to have the following assignment explained

Tags: variables, go, integer, variable-assignment

I'm new to Golang and would like to have the following code explained to me, particularly the last part when you assign `Pos(0)`. What is `Pos(0)` exactly? Thanks!

```
type Pos uint

var NoPos = Pos(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). It is there to convert `0` to type `Pos`. It could also be rewritten without a conversion like this:

```
var NoPos Pos = 0
```